# Remote Desktop Connection from Login Screen

Tags: hyper-v, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

**My Environment:**
I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with Hyper-V installed.  Inside of Hyper-V, I have a few other virtual desktops running (all Windows operating systems with Remote Desktop enabled).

**My Goal:**
I was wondering if it would be possible to log directly into one of these virtual machines from the physical machine's login screen.  Effectively bypassing the host and starting a remote desktop connection with the guest.

**My Motivation:**
I only have one physical box, and I want to give each individual user their own personal desktop environment.  If possible, I do not want to give them permission to the host box.

Comment: I suppose the obvious solution would be to dual-boot (possibly even into VHDs) for each user.  The one thing I forgot to mention though is that one of the virtual machines is a headless server that I want to always remain on.

Comment: maybe a domain user solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging in directly from the loginscreen is not possible. Maybe someone writes a plugin to do that.

My option would be a thinclient with rdp.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get almost what you want if you create a completely non-privileged guest account on the Hyper-V management OS.  Then have the non-privileged users log into that and then use Remote Desktop to get to their VMs.

Answer (score 0):

If each of the guest computers have RDP enabled then you can log into them from any computer, not just the host computer. Is it the case that you only have the host computer and no other computers so each user has to use the host computer to get to the guest computers?

Comment: Correct, no other computers are available at this time. :) Basically, my roommate wants to use my home server for everyday use, but there's no way I'm giving him access to the actual server.